# jQuery ajax load page from success

Tags: php, jquery

The code I am using is working ok but I am a bit stuck at trying to load a new page from a success function. The simplest way to put it is, how do I filter data coming from the php backend to make decisions? for example, I set a condition in the backend testajax.php page and in the ajax success function test for certain conditions. In php it would be something along the lines of using the if statement. I am quite new to jquery so would appreciate some guidance as to how to achieve this. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "testajax.php",
  data: data,
  success: function (data) {

   $('#login_message').html(data);
   //$(ok).val('Logged In');
   //$("#login").get(0).reset();
   //$("#form").dialog('close');
   $.mobile.changePage( "admin/index.php/", { transition: "slideup"} );
  },
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
   alert('There was an exception thrown somewhere');
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

testajax.php

```
<?php
  // test wether the user session is already set
  session_start();
  $userpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $userpost;
   if($_SESSION['user']=='admin') {
     echo 'Welcome Admin';
     // for example, test data in ajax for 
     // this flag and if equal 1 then load admin/index.php
     $flag = 'admin';
     // end of flag
     echo $flag;
  }
  else
     echo 'Unknown User';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  // test wether the user session is already set
  session_start();
  $userpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $userpost;
   if($_SESSION['user']=='admin') {        
     $flag = 'admin';        
     echo $flag;
  }
  else
     echo 'Unknown User';
  }
?>
```

ajax part

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "testajax.php",
  data: data,
  success: function (data) {

   $('#login_message').html(data);
   if(data==='admin')
   { 
    //redirect
    $.mobile.changePage( "admin/index.php/", { transition: "slideup"} );
   }

  },
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
   alert('There was an exception thrown somewhere');
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

Comment: 3nigma is this the correct way to load a page in ajax $.mobile.changePage( "admin/index.php/", { transition: "slideup"} ); or is there some other method? because I am new I am trying to cover all bases. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you using if statements within the jquery code so within you ajax callback you could use:

```
if (data == 'Unknown User') {
  alert('Unknown User');
} else {
  //Do some other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the request if it's an ajax request and output only the content that is needed for the ajax part.

```
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
      //request by ajax
    }
    else
    {
      //regular request.
    }
```